# How to get job parameters in tasklet if we execute particular method in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, jobs

I have 3 steps specified for executing 3 difference job. lets say a, b, and c. I configured that in my spring batch xml. This should be configured in such as way that if I execute a, then on success only it will execute b otherwise breaks and same for b. Also I want to execute particular step based on one of the job parameter input. (If I got input of b then it will execute directly b, not a).
My spring batch xml:

```xml
<batch:job id ="MyJob">
<batch:step id = "a">
<batch:tasklet ref="myJavaClassService" method="callingA"/>
<batch:next on="*" next="b"/>
<batch:next on="FAILED" next="exit"/>
</batch:step>
<batch:step id = "b">
<batch:tasklet ref="myJavaClassService" method="callingB"/>
<batch:next on="*" next="c"/>
<batch:next on="FAILED" next="exit"/>
</batch:step>
<batch:step id = "c">
<batch:tasklet ref="myJavaClassService" method="callingC"/>
<batch:next on="FAILED" next="exit"/>
</batch:step>
<batch:step id = "exit">
<batch:tasklet ref="myJavaClassService" method="exit"/>
</batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

My java service class is as follows:

```java
@Service("myJavaClassService")
class MyJavaClassService
{
    public void callingA() {  /* Some Operation --- */ }
    public void callingB() {  /* Some Operation --- */ }
    public void callingC() {  /* Some Operation --- */ }
    public void exit() {  System.exit(1); }
}
```

My Java main class is as follows:

```java
class MyClassMain
{
/*---- some configuration related code ---*/

JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("JobLauncher");

Job job = (Job) ctx.getBean("MyJob");

JobParametersBuilder jpd = new JobParametersBuilder();
jpd.addString("firstParam");
jpd.addString("secondParam");
jpd.addString("thirdParam");

JobParameters jp = jpd.toParameters();

JobExecution result = jobLauncher.run(job, jp);

}
```

I am stuck on following points:

How can I get all the job parameters in my Service class? I tried implementing `Tasklet`, `ItemPrcoess`, `StepListener`, etc but none worked out for me.

How can I execute particular step based on job parameter, lets say I want to execute directly "step id = b"?

How can I give return type from any of the calling methods, like I require to get one output value from `callingA` and that output value I need to pass to `callingB` method, how can I do that.

I tried to get job parameters in my calling method using `@BeforeStep` method of `StepExecutionListener` but `beforeMethod` is not executing, not sure why. For example: I wrote the line
`String first param = executionContext.getStepExecution.getString("firstparam")` in `beforeStep` method, but I am not able to get first param value in my `callingA` method.
Thus, I realized, none of the listener is working in my case.

Please note that I am getting a call inside my method `callingA` but I am not able to get the job parameters.

Also, based on my requirements, I would appreciate if you have any other feasible solution. I don't have any requirement of chunk or any reader writer processor jobs. Simple calling 3 methods which has a code of executing different python jobs.

Comment: have a bean in your project, which contains all the values. Autowire that in all the classes you need it. Personally, I would recommend not to use xml configuration for your batches. annotations work great

Comment: Appreciate your reply here. I have one bean class, but question is how I can assigned values from jobparameters to that bean class and how to get that in my service.

Comment: I assume you have heard of setters and getters? or use a properties file. Spring has a few options for that

Comment: Yeah I do have bean class of setter getter methods but question is how I can get job parameters in my service method and then assign those values to my bean class. My `@Before` , `@BeforeStep` method none working. Parameters are of real time which passing through `joblauncher` so properties file not applicable to me.